The inequality $2\sum_{p ~\mathrm{prime}}(\log p)~ K_1 ~(2\log p) \le1.$
My question is how to show the Bessel prime inequality:
$$2\sum_{p ~\mathrm{prime}}(\log p)~ K_1 ~(2\log p) \le1.$$
Numerical attempts by me show that using the first $500$ primes yields $0.945$ but I would like an analytic solution.
I noticed this equals:
$$\sum_{p ~\mathrm{prime}}(\log p^2)~ K_1 ~(\log p^2) \le1.$$

Is $K_1$ the modified Bessel function of the first kind ?

@Kermatoni modified bessel of the second kind
